# Javascript canvas render centered text with an image

Tags: javascript, canvas, text, centering, text-rendering

I am starting to work with the Javascript canvas (CanvasRenderingContext2D) and I am finding centering text really hard to do. I am using the following piece of code to center the text both horizontally and vertically:

```
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
```

I know I can use `ctx.measureText()` to get the width of a string but the height is not available in the returned object. I tried using advanced text metrics but they seem to be a new thing and my Firefox build (latest in the Ubuntu store) doesn't support it yet and I want my webpage to be at least compatible with 1 year-old browser versions.

I am being able to center the text right now but the problem is centering two objects (an image and a piece of text), like the second situation in the following image, where the objects must be centered together (like they were a single object that contained both the image and the text):

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_P9826O1x0bFhRqPEKz_AB18iYNPa5CP/view?usp=sharing

The only way I can think of doing that is by knowing the height of the text, because I need to calculate both the position of the image and the text (pseudo-code):

```
//I can do this
image.x = (canvas.width / 2) - image.width;
text.x = (canvas.width / 2) - text.width;
//But not this
image.y = (canvas.height / 2) - (image.height / 2) - (text.height / 2);
//Do this with top-left text align 
text.y = (canvas.height / 2) + (image.height / 2) - (text.height / 2)
```

Sadly, the only ways I found of getting the height of the text was through "it kinda works" approximations and rendering the text to a canvas and getting its pixel data to see the lowest pixel, which is bad for performance.

What can I do to fix this and get the text height in a better way? Is ti possible to center them without even having the height of the text? I would like to keep using the canvas element because this will be for a game, so I can't use HTML and CSS to center objects. Please, only use plain Javascript (no things like query).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you know your font size, then you know how tall a line of text is. Note that text characters vary in height, and rarely fill the whole height of the line, but hopefully this value is close enough to give you the results you want?

Comment: It fails with tall characters like fs and short ones like underscores. I also don't know if I should use pt fonts or px fonts